# How do I render CSS in a maven webapp project?

Tags: html, jsp

I am creating a web application using servelets. My file structure is shown below. I have linked my css files but the styles are not rendered on the page. How do I solve this?

[image: project file structure]

In index.html file I have this to call the css file.

```
<link href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```